# Catch most derived exceptions?

Tags: c#, exception

In .NET, when catching exceptions, should I always catch derived exceptions (so not ArgumentException but the derived types)?

Also:

If I am asked to use error codes, would this be in the constructor like so?:

throw new Exception("4000", ex);

Or a custom exception type with an errorcode property? (This may get confusing with exception types like SqlException which have error codes mapping to SQL Server errors).

Thanks

Comment: Where do the error codes come from? Are those error codes native Win32 error codes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Catch the broadest exception that you know how to handle.

   In general, this means you'll be catching a pretty specific exception.  And some exceptions, like `ArgumentException`s, shouldn't be caught at all b/c they indicate a logic error as opposed to a runtime error.  One place where I've found catching a broader exception useful is in the case of File I/O.  An `IOException` can be a practical higher-level exception to catch.
2. If you are asked to use error codes, you could get away with using the message property of an exception to wrap it, but I would never use that as a reason to avoid throwing an appropriately typed exception.  This is because there are two separate concerns here:

   a. The error code is there to provide a specific piece of information that can be looked up in the case of a failure in the field.  It should never be used to discriminate between exception types programmatically b/c the language has a specific facility designed for that: exception types.

   b. The appropriately typed exception is there to provide a programmatic way of distinguishing between exceptions.  The language is designed for it, use it.  Don't *ever* throw a plain `Exception`.

   I would probably throw an error code into the [`Exception.Data` collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.data.aspx).  This avoids overwriting messages in `Exception.Message` that would otherwise be very helpful for diagnostic purposes.

Comment: I'm not sure there's much basis in general for regarding ArgumentException as more or less "severe" than many other types. What one really needs to know when catching an exception is the state of the system (and whether the routine that threw the exception has affected it). If trying to e.g. parse a file, I'm not sure there's much value in validating all fields before calling routines that would throw ArgumentException if their arguments are invalid, unless my own code could do something more useful than throw an exception given the invalid input. So I hardly see that it implies "logic error".

Answer (score 2):

This depends on if you want to catch an exact exception or a group of different types of exceptions.

Sometimes you want to add handling for 1 exact exception only.    Other times your exception handling will be the same for any type of exception so you can just put catch or just catch `Exception` to see what the exception is.

For example you may want to catch only 1 exact exception and no other exception handling. You would do that when you know further up the call stack you are catching the rest of the exceptions but you want to ignore just the one you're catching exactly.